# C# Uploading files via HTTP

Tags: c#, php, file, upload

is it possible to upload files to web page and then access file data on website using  $_FILES['file'] in php?

Comment: Yes, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131425/send-a-file-via-http-post-with-c.

Comment: Why is this titled and tagged as C# but you're looking to access the files via PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code to send file name to php file as POST value and it also stores the returned value

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
byte[] bret = client.UploadFile(webpath, "POST", filepath);
string sret = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bret);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your webserver in some way to answer POST requests with the appropriate actions. If you can't acces your server, you can't upload to it with C#; there is no 'standard' way to do this.