# File.Copy with urls c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, copy

It´s possible to use two urls with File.Copy with C#? I´m getting different errors :

1. URI formats are not supported
2. The given path's format is not supported.

There is a question some similar but is not answered.

I want copy from a directory that is in server1 to another server and the urls are http

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean http URLs, for example? Absolutely not... It would really help if you could give more information about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use File.Copy only if we are not talking about an FTP. in that case you can use the code below

if you have an FTP you can use the below code:

```
public void ftpfile(string ftpfilepath, string inputfilepath)  
{  
    string ftphost = "127.0.0.1";  
    //here correct hostname or IP of the ftp server to be given  

    string ftpfullpath = "ftp://" + ftphost + ftpfilepath;  
    FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpfullpath);  
    ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userid", "password");  
    //userid and password for the ftp server to given  

    ftp.KeepAlive = true;  
    ftp.UseBinary = true;  
    ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;  
    FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(inputfilepath);  
    byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];  
    fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);  
    fs.Close();  
    Stream ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream();  
    ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);  
    ftpstream.Close();  
}
```

then you can do

```
ftpfile(@"/testfolder/testfile.xml", @"c:\testfile.xml");
```

if we are talking about a shared folder on the same network you can do the below:

```
File.Copy(filepath, "\\\\192.168.1.28\\Files");
```

for HTTP you can use the below:

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
    client.UploadFile(address, filePath);
}
```

source:

[Send a file via HTTP POST with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131425/send-a-file-via-http-post-with-c)

Comment: Sorry Massimiliano here "you can use File.Copy only if we are not talking about an FTP" you wanna say http?

Comment: I have a question with WebClient is only valid for Uri, String or String, String but not for two differents URLS?

Comment: have a look at all the overloads:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadfile.aspx
Anyway if you need to access to the source file via HTTP/FTP you have to download it first

Answer (score -1):

Look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx

If you mean http urls it is not possible.

Comment: Thanks Hooch , I don't waste my time with File.Copy, I´ll try another thing