# how to upload file via c# post request? ownCloud

Tags: c#, http-post, owncloud

i`m using ownCloud (open source cloud) and i have a form to upload files
the form sending the post request to upload.php file that handle the upload.
the request have a lot of fields and need to send all info and cookie.

i need to develop a c# code to upload files to the cloud.
the best way in my opinion is to make a request similar to the request that the form does.
what do you think? any suggestions?

p.s i read the following solutions but it is not working.
[Sending Files using HTTP POST in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738847/sending-files-using-http-post-in-c-sharp)
http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/268661-how-upload-file-via-c-code
[Upload files with HTTPWebrequest (multipart/form-data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data)

thanks

here is some of the code:

the form:

```
<form data-upload-id='1'
id="data-upload-form"
class="file_upload_form"
action="<?php print_unescaped(OCP\Util::linkTo('files', 'ajax/upload.php')); ?>"
method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data"
target="file_upload_target_1">

<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" id="max_upload" value="<?php p($_['uploadMaxFilesize']) ?>">

<input type="hidden" name="requesttoken" value="<?php p($_['requesttoken']) ?>" id="requesttoken">
<input type="hidden" class="max_human_file_size" value="(max <?php p($_['uploadMaxHumanFilesize']); ?>)">
 <input type="hidden" name="dir" value="<?php p($_['dir']) ?>" id="dir">
<input type="file" id="file_upload_start" name='files[]'/>
<a href="#" class="svg"></a>
                </form>
```

This the way the request seen to me:

```
enter code here

Request URL:http://my-url/owncloud/index.php/apps/files/ajax/upload.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview parsed
POST /owncloud/index.php/apps/files/ajax/upload.php HTTP/1.1
Host: my-url
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 730
Accept: */*
requesttoken: 0bbcd458174e76e139ad
Origin: http://my-url
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.66 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryVhC3ZFEhWXiSUZYT
Referer: http://my-url/owncloud/index.php/apps/files
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: oc_username=tal; oc_token=f24c041e992624d10cabbaa16aa6aeea; oc_remember_login=1; __utma=220528984.2016256779.1375771228.1375771228.1375862096.2; __utmz=220528984.1375771228.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); olfsk=olfsk4827894743066281; hblid=QHgh67nWTyXfpzWe6B1Tj9Z3JM0QBCfA; 510e8a1de6274=eqavm1nikkon6ush7con3o6ar6
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryVhC3ZFEhWXiSUZYT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MAX_FILE_SIZE"

537919488
------WebKitFormBoundaryVhC3ZFEhWXiSUZYT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="requesttoken"

0bbcd458174e76e139ad
------WebKitFormBoundaryVhC3ZFEhWXiSUZYT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="dir"

/
------WebKitFormBoundaryVhC3ZFEhWXiSUZYT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename="bg.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundaryVhC3ZFEhWXiSUZYT--
Response Headersview parsed
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 08 Sep 2013 07:21:02 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze16
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 132
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

i tried this code

```
 public static void HttpUploadFile(string url, string file, string paramName, string contentType, NameValueCollection nvc) 
            {



string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
                byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");

                HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                wr.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
                wr.Method = "POST";
                wr.KeepAlive = true;
                wr.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;


                Stream rs = wr.GetRequestStream();

                string formdataTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"\r\n\r\n{1}";
                foreach (string key in nvc.Keys)
                {
                    rs.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
                    string formitem = string.Format(formdataTemplate, key, nvc[key]);
                    byte[] formitembytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formitem);
                    rs.Write(formitembytes, 0, formitembytes.Length);
                }
                rs.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);

                string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n";
                string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, paramName, file, contentType);
                byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
                rs.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);

                FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int bytesRead = 0;
                while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0) 
                {
                    rs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }   
                fileStream.Close();

                byte[] trailer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
                rs.Write(trailer, 0, trailer.Length);   

                //StreamReader reader3 = new StreamReader(rs);
                rs.Close();




                WebResponse wresp = null;
                try 
                {
                    wresp = wr.GetResponse();
                    Stream stream2 = wresp.GetResponseStream();
                    StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2);
                    MessageBox.Show((string.Format("File uploaded, server response is: {0}", reader2.ReadToEnd())));
                    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("File uploaded, server response is: {0}", reader2.ReadToEnd()));

                } 
                catch(Exception ex) 
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Error uploading file", ex);

                    if(wresp != null) 
                    {
                        wresp.Close();
                        wresp = null;
                    }
                } 
                finally
                {
                    wr = null;
                }
            }
```

the calling function:

```
NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
                nvc.Add("id", "TTR");
        nvc.Add("btn-submit-photo", "Upload");
        FilesClass.HttpUploadFile("http://192.168.49.108/owncloud/index.php/apps/files/ajax/upload.php", @"C:\t.txt", "files[]", "text/plain", nvc);
```

the response from the server is {"data":{"message":"Authentication error"},"status":"error"}
that mean that i was rejected by upload.php 
maybe i need to send the cookie?

Comment: You said that the answers in the questions you linked to didn't help you, but you didn't say what you tried and what happened when you did.  It'd be more helpful if you paste some code that you tried, and what happened vs. what you expected to happen.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to simulate a POST upload (which ownCloud makes fairly difficult due to security issues) you can use WebDAV to upload the file.

Simply send a PUT request to `http://example.com/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/some/path`