# Post a picture using webrequest in c#

Tags: c#, python, .net

I have the following python code how to post a picture through webservice:

```
product_image = requests.post(
'https://client.planorama.com/tapi/v1/product_image/', 
data={ 'product_id': 1784682 }, 
files={ "file": open(my_image.jpg, 'rb') } 
)
```

Can anyone help me to do the same thing in C#,

Answer (score 0):

We are rather spoiled with the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library in python.

Are you running .NET 4 or 4.5? If so, take a look at Joshcodes answer to [Sending Files using HTTP POST in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738847/sending-files-using-http-post-in-c-sharp) - it uses `Microsoft.Net.Http` which is by *far* the best HTTP library in the .NET world these days.

UPDATE: I haven't checked this for accuracy yet, but it could go something like this:

```
static HttpResponseMessage UploadFileWithParam(string requestUri, string fileName, string key1, string val1)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            content.Add(new StringContent(val1), key1);
            var fileContent = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(fileName));
            fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = fileName
            };
            content.Add(fileContent);
            return client.PostAsync(requestUri, content).Result;
        }
    }
}

// UploadFileWithParam("http://example.com", @"c:\...", "param1", "value1").Dump();
```

Comment: thank you for the response. The proble that I have is: I have to pass two parameters which are the productId and the file(picture). in python it's easy but in .net I know how to read the image using filestream but I don't how to pass it as a parameter value

Comment: I've added a snippet above that might help you. I'd try it out with LINQPad (https://www.linqpad.net) and compare the requests between the python and the .NET version via fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Comment: Thank you for the Update. I'll try it. hopefully it will solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

[Multipart Form Post in C#](http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/multipart-form-post-in-c) includes a simple C# class using [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with a provided (working) example.

Comment: thank you for the link. but it doesn't show how to post a picture as a parameter value. the parameter name is file, how to pass the picture as file value?

Comment: It does: `postParameters.Add("file", new FormUpload.FileParameter(data, "my_image.jpg", "image/jpg"));` (data being the filestream containing the picture) is what you want

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I want but will I use the same method to pass the productId? because the file and productId have to be all posted. I also need to use credentials to get access. how do I go about?

Comment: As far as I can see from your question, the product_id not a file and should therefore be provided as normal post parameter. Take a look at the class, the author made some comments about authentification.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it. I hope it's going to work because I've struggling for days