# Send file and Parameter to URL in WPF

Tags: c#, python, wpf, rest, flask-restful

I want to send a Zipfile and 2 parameter to a RESTFull API method . I have tried "[Sending Files using HTTP POST in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738847/sending-files-using-http-post-in-c-sharp)" but didn't get expected result. The api method see my request by empty parameters. 
what's my wrong ? And what shall i do ???

My target has been powered by flask(a python framework)

here is my tried code:

```
public static void UploadFilesToRemoteUrl(string url, string[] files, string logpath,  NameValueCollection nvc)
{
    long length = 0;
    string boundary = "----------------------------" +
    DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");


    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    httpWebRequest2.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
    httpWebRequest2.Method = "POST";
    httpWebRequest2.KeepAlive = true;
    httpWebRequest2.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

    Stream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

    byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" +
    boundary + "\r\n");

    string formdataTemplate = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\";\r\n\r\n{1}";

    foreach (string key in nvc.Keys)
    {
        string formitem = string.Format(formdataTemplate, key, nvc[key]);
        byte[] formitembytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formitem);
        memStream.Write(formitembytes, 0, formitembytes.Length);
    }


    memStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);

    string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\n Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {
        //string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, "file" + i, files[i]);
        string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, "uplTheFile", files[i]);

        byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);

        memStream.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);

        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(files[i], FileMode.Open,
        FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            memStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        memStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);

        fileStream.Close();
    }


    httpWebRequest2.ContentLength = memStream.Length;
    Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest2.GetRequestStream();

    memStream.Position = 0;
    byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[memStream.Length];
    memStream.Read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
    memStream.Close();
    requestStream.Write(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    WebResponse webResponse2 = httpWebRequest2.GetResponse();

    Stream stream2 = webResponse2.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2);


    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(reader2.ReadToEnd());

    webResponse2.Close();
    httpWebRequest2 = null;
    webResponse2 = null
}
```

Comment: *Didn't get the expected result* What does that mean? what happens when you run this code?

Comment: when i run this code didn't see any exception also didn't send file to destination or server

Comment: What is the `WebReponse` statuscode?