# Upload file with the help of URI

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a URI hosted on a server

```
http://192.161.0.45/MywebPage/Image
```

Image is the name of the folder
i want to upload file on that URI
Please help me

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show some code so we can see where you're getting lost. Are you trying to upload an entire folder?

Comment: First of all, you cannot just copy something to a http foler, you would need some acces to this, either via FTP or via direct access to the file system. With that uri alone, you will be unable to upload anything to the folder.

Comment: Dave I have tried few option like sharing that folder with read/write access and i have used FTP also, but i wonder if there any way that file can be uploaded via HTTP.

@Ken isn't there any way we can upload file through HTTP

Comment: HTTP is not a protocol to upload files with. If you want to upload using FTP you would need the login details for the webserver after which you can "easily" upload files to the server. You say you tried sharing the folder with read/write access. Does this mean you can directly work on the server in some way then? If so the problem might not be as hard to solve. Can you show some code as to what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [this approach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144229%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.UploadFile(uri, pathToLocalFile);
```

This question is realy close to your:
[Send a file via HTTP POST with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131425/send-a-file-via-http-post-with-c-sharp)