# Send file using PHP POST in C#

Tags: c#, .net, csv

I want to send csv file using php POST method in C#.
I'm using WebClient. I know how I can upload file.
But I don't know how I can combine send file with other parameters in NameValueCollection.

I have to send few parameters and additionaly CSV file. How I can do this in C#?

Comment: Are you meaning that you're sending it via POST to a PHP script?

Comment: Don't you mean "HTTP POST"?

Comment: I have website address (php method - I think). And it must be called with HTTP POST method.

Comment: @ogrod87 Your question is slightly misleading, then; your problem is not related to PHP.

Comment: send multipart/form-data -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send a file via HTTP POST with C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131425/send-a-file-via-http-post-with-c-sharp)

Comment: Sorry for duplicate. I found solution there... I've searching for about hour and didn't found this topic.

Answer (score -1):

There is no "PHP POST", just POST or GET (that are part of HTTP request, like many order verbs).
You should consider using [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) in order to send data via POST.

Comment: Isn't it an answer to his question ?

Comment: Link-only answer if anything, and that's not quite encouraged.

Comment: @Atlasmaybe Not a very useful one, unfortunately; flesh it out with how he could use HttpWebRequest. Also, you're saying "just POST or GET" - that's actually incorrect, you're missing PUT, DELETE, HEAD, etc.

Comment: Or see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data?lq=1

Comment: @AdrianWragg : I'm aware of those verbs. I have omitted them in purpose to not confuse him in my answer.

Comment: @Atlasmaybe You should also explain why OP should switch from *WebClient* to *HttpWebRequest*. Which problem will it solve?

Comment: @Atlasmaybe You've used the word "just", making your sentence read as if you're stating that those are the only options; otherwise, why include GET?

Comment: @AdrianWragg : It seems that my english is not so good. That was not what I wanted to say.

Comment: @I4V : The question is answered by its author, but I keep in mind your advice for further answers.

Comment: @Atlasmaybe No problem. Please take comments as being constructive, and keep going. :)