# Best way to send image data to a server using WebClient

Tags: c#, winforms, webclient

I'm using Webclient to try and send my image I've got on my winform application to a central server. However I've never used WebClient before and I'm pretty sure what I'm doing is wrong.

First of all, I'm storing and displaying my image on my form like so:

```
_screenCap = new ScreenCapture();
_screenCap.OnUpdateStatus += _screen_CapOnUpdateStatus;
capturedImage = imjObj;
imagePreview.Image = capturedImage;
```

I've set up an event manager to update my imagePreview image when ever I take a screenshot. Then displaying it when ever the status changes like this:

```
private void _screen_CapOnUpdateStatus(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e)
{  
  imagePreview.Image = e.CapturedImage;
}
```

With this image I'm trying to pass it to my server like so:

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.UploadData("http://filelocation.com/uploadimage.html", "POST", imagePreview.Image);
 }
```

I know I should convert the image to a byte[] but I've no idea how to do that. Could someone please point me in the right direction of go about doing this properly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert image in byte array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801275/how-to-convert-image-in-byte-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can convert to byte[] like this

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    imageIn.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
    return  ms.ToArray();
}
```

if you have path to image, you can also do this

```
 byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("imagepath");
```

Answer (score 3):

This may help you...

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
     client.UploadFile(address, filePath);
}
```

Refered from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131425/send-a-file-via-http-post-with-c-sharp).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `ContentType` header to that of `image/gif` or possibly `binary/octet-stream` and call `GetBytes()` on the image.

```
using (var wc = new WebClient { UseDefaultCredentials = true })
{
    wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "image/gif");
    //wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream");
    wc.UploadData("http://filelocation.com/uploadimage.html",
        "POST",
        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(imagePreview.Image));
}
```