# Webclient image upload to server

Tags: c#, winforms, webclient

This is a follow on from my last question ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444479/best-way-to-send-image-data-to-a-server-using-webclient/18444570?noredirect=1#18444570)) as I don't think I gave enough information the first time around and i can't delete it.

I've got my image converted to a byte array but the follow on help and suggestions made it seem like that the image I wanted to save needed to first exist on my computer. Where, in fact, the image I want to take only exists in the picture box (its a screen grab). When I check my server to see if the image has been passed over, I don't see anything and nothing prompts me to name my image file or anything.

So my question is thus:

What is the best way for my to upload a screen grab from my application, using webclient, to my central server? Ideally the functionality I would like would be very similar to that of saving the image to my computer. The only difference is, it's not my hard drive I'm saving the image on. It's a server somewhere.

Comment: You need to write the page on the server to accept the Post you made in your previous question.  It will take the stream and save the file.  You will be responsible for the filename and there will not be a "prompt".

Comment: Do you have any links that can show me how to do this?

Comment: MVC version: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx

Comment: webforms: http://imar.spaanjaars.com/414/storing-uploaded-files-in-a-database-or-in-the-file-system-with-aspnet-20

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-simple-file-uploads-in-aspnet

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23127250/c-sharp-upload-file-by-webclient/40223394#40223394