# C# upload file by webclient

Tags: c#, image, file-upload, webclient, image-uploading

I uploaded a file by webclient. But upload success and response link file. But when I go to the file manager I don't have the file in my account. Why ?

This is my code.

```
private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Headers.Add("OurSecurityHeader", "encryptedvalue");
        wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0");     
        wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "__cfduid=d56b9e4ca0801822e9231936c70518ec91397746478931; __utma=259844498.1111893290.1397796877.1397796877.1397802609.2; __utmc=259844498; __utmz=259844498.1397796877.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); login=KimJanParkC1; xfss=g7prlsjg15zl57h4; __zlcid=%7B%22mID%22%3A%22OPdgp3o75YUWIg%22%2C%22sid%22%3A%22140417.91047.473AFH5T%22%7D; __utmb=259844498.17.10.1397802609; sthumb=500x500; _mcnc=1");     
        wc.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(wc_UploadProgressChanged);
        wc.UploadFileCompleted += new UploadFileCompletedEventHandler(UploadFileCallback);
        wc.UploadFileAsync(new Uri("http://img102.imagetwist.com/cgi-bin/upload.cgi?upload_id="), "POST", txtPath.Text);
    }

    void wc_UploadFileCompleted(object sender, UploadFileCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // GET DOWNLOAD LINK
        MessageBox.Show("Upload Finished");
    }

    void wc_UploadProgressChanged(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        pgbStatus.Maximum = (int)e.TotalBytesToSend;
        pgbStatus.Value = (int)e.BytesSent;
        label6.Text = ((int)e.BytesSent * 100) / (int)e.TotalBytesToSend + "%";
    }

    public void UploadFileCallback(Object sender, UploadFileCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // GET RESPOND DOWNLOAD LINK
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument hd = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        hd.LoadHtml(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Result));
        txtResult.Text = hd.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
    }
```

Comment: can you please subscribe *UploadFileCompleted* event & check *e.status* property ?

Comment: I have, but not work. File upload dont have my account, i dont' where is the file upload ?

Comment: its hard to understand your problem now. please elaborate fully & post your full code.

Comment: I uploaded full code. When i check txtResult . I saw my account logged . And file upload success. But not have in file manager

Comment: And have a problem . wc_UploadFileCompleted never called . MessageBox.Show("Upload Finished") never appear

Comment: UploadFileCompleted event code won't fire as you set another method named UploadFileCallback. can you please check e.status property in that callback method.

Answer (score 1):

In windows side:

```
private void uploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    var dialogResult = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
    if (dialogResult != DialogResult.OK) return;
    Upload(openFileDialog.FileName);
} 

private void Upload(string fileName)
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    client.UploadFileCompleted += new UploadFileCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
    client.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
    var uri = new Uri("http://www.yoursite.com/UploadFile/");
    try
    {
        client.Headers.Add("fileName", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName));
        var data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
        client.UploadDataAsync(uri, data);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void Completed(object sender, UploadFileCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Error?.Message ?? "Uploaded Successfully!");
}

private void ProgressChanged(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

In server side you should use WebApi:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<object> UploadFile()
{
    var file = await Request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    var fileName = Request.Headers.GetValues("fileName").FirstOrDefault();
    var filePath = "/upload/files/";
    try
    {
        File.WriteAllBytes(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filePath) + fileName , file);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // ignored
    }
    return null;
}
```