# Post byte array to Web API server using HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, dotnet-httpclient

I want to post this data to Web API server:

```
public sealed class SomePostRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}
```

Using this code for server:

```
[Route("Incoming")]
[ValidateModel]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostIncomingData(SomePostRequest requestData)
{
    // POST logic here
}
```

and this - for client:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:25001/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "id", "1" },
    { "content", "123" }
});

var result = await client.PostAsync("api/SomeData/Incoming", content);
result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

everything works fine (at least, debugger stops at breakpoint in `PostIncomingData`).

Since there is a `byte` array, I don't want to serialize it as JSON, and want to post it as binary data to decrease network traffic (something like `application/octet-stream`).

How this can be achieved?

I've tried to play with `MultipartFormDataContent`, but looks like I just can't understand, how `MultipartFormDataContent` will match signature of controller's method.

E.g., replacing content to this:

```
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
content.Add(new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "id", "1" } }));

var binaryContent = new ByteArrayContent(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 });
binaryContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
content.Add(binaryContent, "content");

var result = await client.PostAsync("api/SomeData/Incoming", content);
result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

leads to error 415 ("Unsupported media type").

Answer (score 38, accepted):

WebAPI v2.1 and beyond [supports BSON (Binary JSON) out of the box](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/bson-support-in-web-api-21), and even has a `MediaTypeFormatter` included for it. This means you can post your entire message in binary format.

If you want to use it, you'll need to set it in `WebApiConfig`:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Formatters.Add(new BsonMediaTypeFormatter());
    }
}
```

Now, you an use the same `BsonMediaTypeFormatter` at the client side to serialize your request:

```
public async Task SendRequestAsync()
{
    var client = new HttpClient
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.yourserviceaddress.com");
    };

    // Set the Accept header for BSON.
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/bson"));

    var request = new SomePostRequest
    {
        Id = 20,
        Content = new byte[] { 2, 5, 7, 10 }
    };

    // POST using the BSON formatter.
    MediaTypeFormatter bsonFormatter = new BsonMediaTypeFormatter();
    var result = await client.PostAsync("api/SomeData/Incoming", request, bsonFormatter);

    result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

Or, you can use Json.NET to serialize your class to BSON. Then, specify you want to use "application/bson" as your "Content-Type":

```
public async Task SendRequestAsync()
{   
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var bson = new BsonWriter(stream))
    {
        var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();

        var request = new SomePostRequest
        {
            Id = 20,
            Content = new byte[] { 2, 5, 7, 10 }
        };

        jsonSerializer.Serialize(bson, request);

        var client = new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.yourservicelocation.com")
        };

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/bson"));

        var byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(stream.ToArray());
        byteArrayContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/bson");

        var result = await client.PostAsync(
                "api/SomeData/Incoming", byteArrayContent);

        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. Actually, the link you've provided contains more simple example for the client side.

Comment: @Dennis It uses the `BsonMediaTypeFormatter` to serialize. I guess you can have it either way. I'll add another example to my answer.

Comment: Your second code sample missing content type:

`var byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(stream.ToArray());
byteArrayContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/bson");
 var result = await client.PostAsync(
                "api/SomeData/Incoming", byteArrayContent);`

Comment: How are you consuming this in the controller...? using your 2nd example there, I get `UnsupportedMediaType` exception on the server - .Net5 web api

Answer (score 17):

I convert `Byte Array` into `Base64 String` to post:

```
await client.PostAsJsonAsync( apiUrl,  
    new  {
        message = "",
        content = Convert.ToBase64String(yourByteArray),
    }
);
```

and receiver can convert the `Base64 String` back to  `Byte Array` by:

```
string base64Str = (string)postBody.content;
byte[] fileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Str);
```

Comment: Simple and effective

Comment: I would say it's simple but not effective since the base64 string will be about 30% larger. Nevertheless, a working quick solution.

Comment: @RayCheng I'd say it's simple and effective but not efficient.

Comment: it also assumes you have control over the api, which you probably don't

Comment: How should reciever method look like? Where postBody variable is taken from?

Comment: it may be like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37842231/webapi-2-post-with-single-string-parameter-not-working

Comment: While this might not be the best answer to this question it is certainly the answer to my problem

Answer (score 7):

I have created this generic and cross platform method to support the BSON format using the Json.NET library so we can reuse it easier later. It works fine in Xamarin platform as well.

```
public static async HttpResponseMessage PostBsonAsync<T>(string url, T data)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        //Specifiy 'Accept' header As BSON: to ask server to return data as BSON format
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/bson"));

        //Specify 'Content-Type' header: to tell server which format of the data will be posted
        //Post data will be as Bson format                
        var bSonData = HttpExtensions.SerializeBson<T>(data);
        var byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(bSonData);
        byteArrayContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/bson");

        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, byteArrayContent);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        return response;
    }
}
```

The method to help to serialise data to BSON format:

```
public static byte[] SerializeBson<T>(T obj)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (BsonWriter writer = new BsonWriter(ms))
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
        }

        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Then you can use the Post method like this:

```
var response = await PostBsonAsync<SamplePostRequest>("api/SomeData/Incoming", requestData);
```

Comment: return type for PostBson must be Task, Task<T> or void

Comment: @JuanZamora you are right I just updated the code with await keyword

Comment: This is good but HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once per application - this code will likely exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads - see Microsoft docs - any version of .NET - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 2):

Fyi, for protobuf serialization to request body posts

```
        LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest()
        {
            Code = "UserId",
            Password = "myPass",
            CMToken = "eIFt4lYTKGU:APA91bFZPe3XCDL2r1JUJuEQLlN3FoeFw9ULpw8ljEavNdo9Lc_-Qua4w9pTqdOFLTb92Kf03vyWBqkcvbBfYEno4NQIvp21kN9sldDt40eUOdy0NgMRXf2Asjp6FhOD1Kmubx1Hq7pc",
        };
        byte[] rawBytes = ProtoBufSerializer.ProtoSerialize<LoginRequest>(loginRequest);

        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9000/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-protobuf"));

        //var bSonData = HttpExtensions.SerializeBson<T>(data);
        var byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(rawBytes);
        byteArrayContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-protobuf");

        var result = client.PostAsync("Api/Login", byteArrayContent).Result;

        Console.WriteLine(result.IsSuccessStatusCode);
```

Comment: How to consume??

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to send it truly binary like I did with WebClient before not make it multipart.

Using inspiration from this question I got it working this way:

```
HttpClient InternalHttpClient = new HttpClient();
HttpContent BinaryContent = new ByteArrayContent(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 });
byte[] ReceivedData = new byte[0];

using (HttpResponseMessage ResponseMessage = InternalHttpClient.PostAsync("apiurl/binarycomms.aspx", BinaryContent).Result)
{
    using (HttpContent ResponseBytes = ResponseMessage.Content)
    {
        ReceivedData = ResponseBytes.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
    }
}
```

On the server side the code is also fully binary:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

    byte[] Challenge = Page.Request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes);

    Page.Response.BinaryWrite(new byte[] { 10, 20, 30 });
}
```

You can easily add compression to this communication to make the bandwidth usage even smaller.

Love to hear comments should I have missed something or if this is off topic, but it works like a charm for me.