# WebApi 2 POST with single string parameter not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following controller:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // POST api/values
    public IHttpActionResult Post(string filterName)
    {
        return new JsonResult<string>(filterName, new JsonSerializerSettings(), Encoding.UTF8, this);

    }
}
```

WebApi config

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

I use this js code to call the api

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: "/api/values/",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { filterName: "Dirty Deeds" },
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
        var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3;
        if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
            err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).message;
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

I get a 405 method not allowed (post)

Comment: To the web api method add `[HttpPost]` below your comment. Also I believe that the URL is case sensitive, in the javascript it should probably read `Values` with a capital `V`

Comment: Tried that but same error

Comment: Also if you are sending data via the http message (and not the url) you should add `[FromBody]` to the method signature. `([FromBody] string filterName)`

Comment: Your controller method is expecting a string, but you are passing it an object { filterName: "Dirty Deeds" }. Thats a javascript object with one property of filterName. Your controller isn't expecting an object with a property of filterName, just a string.

Comment: When I use FromBody the param filterName is null

Comment: When I set the data: "Dirty deeds" it is also not working

Comment: Check your route setup. Show how you setup your routes

Comment: I added the webApi config in question

Comment: @peinearydevelopment this makes sense to me.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

c#

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost] // added attribute
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] string filterName) // added FromBody as this is how you are sending the data
    {
        return new JsonResult<string>(filterName, new JsonSerializerSettings(), Encoding.UTF8, this);
    }
```

JavaScript

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: "/api/Values/", // be consistent and case the route the same as the ApiController
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: "=Dirty Deeds", // add an = sign
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
        var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3;
        if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
            err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).message;
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

#### Explanation

Because you are only sending a single value add the = sign in front of it so it will be treated like forms encoding. You can also add the content type if you want to make it clear that this is what you are doing to the ajax call.

```
contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

Alternatively you could also send the content via URL OR wrap the content in an object on the server as well as in the ajax call and stringify it.

```
public class Filter {
    public string FilterName {get;set;}
}

public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost] // added attribute
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] Filter filter) // added FromBody as this is how you are sending the data
    {
        return new JsonResult<string>(filter.FilterName, new JsonSerializerSettings(), Encoding.UTF8, this);
    }
```

JavaScript

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: "/api/Values/", // be consistent and case the route the same as the ApiController
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({FilterName: "Dirty Deeds"}), // send as json
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
        var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3;
        if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
            err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).message;
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: This gives no http error but the param filterName is null

Comment: @DannyH - I updated the javascript and tested it, this works.

Comment: Hi, It works for me too. 

three questions:

Why Do I need the [FormBody] Is this also needed when passing an object?

Why the ContentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 

why "=Dirty Deeds"

Comment: And how do I approach this when passing 1 string and 1 object? Same way?

Comment: @DannyH - Web API will only ever allow a single object to be passed in the message body. So for that you should create an aggregate type that you expect that contains all the data you expect and pass that in using my 2nd example I posted. If you have simple types (int, date, etc) you can pass those in as FromUri and pass them in the query string.

Comment: @DannyH - If you have a single simple value that is passed through the http message body Web API will expect it similar to using forms encoding. This is why the = works. Generally these simple values are passed using the URI and complex types are passed using the message body. This is why not too many people run into this scenario.

Comment: @DannyH - [FromBody] constrains the incoming parameter to the message body instead of the URI. Thats how you are posting your data so you should probably add that constraint to the method signature. It is not required and you could pass it via the URI if you remove it.

Comment: I got it working with an object but I didn't use the 
JSON.stringify(
or the [FormBody] and that worked first time.

Comment: @DannyH - if you have more complex objects or java types that might not translate into a json string using the jquery `.ajax` call then JSON.stringify will be required. Better to add it when ever you are sending an object unless you are using a framework like angular that does it for you. Alternatively you can omit it until you run into an error where data is not coming across from your client correctly at which point you can add it.

Comment: Your last example gives me a null value for the filter property FilterName

JSON.stringify({FilterName: "Dirty Deeds"})

Comment: When I remove the JSON.stringify in your second example it works. So I don't need to do JSON.stringify?

Comment: @DannyH - I forgot to add `contentType: 'application/json',`. I updated the example and tested it, should work.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thx for the help

Comment: note that rather than wrapping it in a "dummy" class ("Filter" in the example), you could make the type parameter be "dynamic" like so - and then you can add whatever other fields you like to the object uised on the call w/o having to worry about adding them to the server-side class...
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] dynamic filter) 
    {
        return new JsonResult<string>(filter.FilterName.Value, new JsonSerializerSettings(), Encoding.UTF8, this);
    }

Comment: What if i have to pass an integer?  I am not able to send an integer. I have to change my Web API method to accept "string" parameter instead of "int" and then use  data: '"' + ID + '"', in my ajax call. Why I am not able to send an integer? Why is it always null?

Comment: @SachinPakale - the comments is not the correct place to ask a new question. Please ask a new question using the "Ask Question" button and be sure to include all the relevant detail.

Answer (score 11):

Add `[FromBody]` to the API method signature like `public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]string filterName)` and wrap the ajax data parameter with quotes: `data: '"' + bodyContent + '"'`.

Not very intuitive, but it works.

Comment: @SachinPakale you can do the same way just by changing the parameter type. (`int filterNumber`). The `Controller` should automatically cast the passed value to a `String`