# Cannot post to another domain using ajax despite having CORS enabled

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using MVC.net and sending post data to my Web API 2 controller. I keep getting a 500 internal server error message.

I am trying to post to another domain if that matters? I have 2 visual studio instances running, one acting as the client, the other as the server. I have enabled CORS.

The GET works fine with this set up, but now I'm trying to post.

My controller on the 'server' is

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/cms/")]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]int accountId, [FromBody]string content, [FromBody]string paneId, [FromBody]string url)
{
    //content
}
```

The javascript on the 'client' I'm using is

```
function ajaxStart(type, url, data, successDelegate, failDelegate, errorDelegate) {
    $.ajax({
        type: type.toUpperCase(),
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            successDelegate(response);
        },
        failure: function (e) {
            failDelegate(e.statusText);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            errorDelegate(e.statusText);  //always hit
        }
    })
}
```

The data is created with (I've purposely used nonsense strings just to ensure there is nothing wrong with the formatting)

```
var data = JSON.stringify({ accountId: 1, paneId: "_selectedPaneNumber", url: "_url", content: "content" });
```

And the 'header' view in Google Chrome Dev Tools shows:

[image]

I have no idea what I've done wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebApi 2 POST with single string parameter not wokring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37842231/webapi-2-post-with-single-string-parameter-not-wokring)

Comment: I've totally updated my post and now it's not a dupe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The javascript on the client side appears fine. The problem seems to be with the ApiController's action and parameter binding.

> At most one parameter is allowed to read from the message body. So this will not work:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]int accountId, [FromBody]string content, [FromBody]string paneId, [FromBody]string url) { ... }
```

> The reason for this rule is that the request body might be stored in a non-buffered stream that can only be read once.

Source: [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API : Using [FromBody]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody)

Consider creating a model in the action server side

```
public class MyModel {
    public int accountId { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
    public string paneId { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}
```

And update the action to expect that.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/cms/")]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] MyModel model) { 
    //code removed for brevity
}
```

Comment: This is great. I had already made an object and so new how to get it working, but as I'm learning I couldn't work out why FromBody didn't work. Thank you. Will mark as answer when the site allows me. And award bounty in 24 hours!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send a string as the body do the following:

- Add the header: `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
- Change the string value in the body so it is prefixed with a `=` character: `=5`

Comment: The same issue continues. The value passed is always null

Comment: I'm sorry, I totally edited the question, this is no longer relevant

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions - I see that. For the next time though I would recommend starting a new question when working through a larger problem instead of morphing the same question multiple times. Doing the latter this is generally frowned upon and is also referred to as a "chameleon" question. Anyways, I am glad that you have the answers you need to keep on coding.

Comment: Please delete this answer though... some one has downvoted you (and I upvoted to prevent you having a negative score). I'm sorry about a chameleon question, that was not the intention.