# How to call a method in a REST Webservice that contains [FromBody] in C#

Tags: asp.net, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api, httpwebrequest

I am getting an error when i try to submit a POST request to a method that exists in WEB API, the sent parameter is always NULL, below i am going to submit the WEB API POST method:

```
    public string Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(value);

        return jsonObject.ToString();
    }
```

I am sure that the above method is working, as i tested it with POSTMAN, below i am posting the method that is calling the REST WEB API:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string fullURL = "http:/localhost:54029/api/values";
        //Creating a Webrequest with any URL.
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fullURL);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        //Defining Method type that will be used with this webrequest
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        //Creating the JSON Object with the required properties.
        var json = new JObject(
                                        new JProperty("Id", "ee288h0emlya"),
                                        new JProperty("isDone", "False"),
                                        new JProperty("stage", "Preparation"),
                                        new JProperty("status", "Done"));


        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            //Writing to the web service, emptying and closing the stream.
            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }
        //Get the response from the server.
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            //Saving the response to result variable.
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
```

When i am calling the first method using the second one, the parameter value is always **null** and therefore i get an empty response and error.

Can someone help please?

Comment: How are you posting json using postman? Please share

Comment: i am copying the JSON object like this:                                                                    "{\r\n  \"documentId\": \"Hmmm\",\r\n  \"isDone\": \"YES\",\r\n  \"stage\": \"Preparations\",\r\n  \"status\": \"Done\"\r\n}"                                                                            And when it is recieved at the REST service i can handle it and convert it back into JSON object instead of a string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebApi 2 POST with single string parameter not wokring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37842231/webapi-2-post-with-single-string-parameter-not-wokring)

Answer (score 0):

If you are accepting parameter as string then you should send it also as string:

```
string json = "\"{ \\\"documentId\\\": \\\"Hmmm\\\", \\\"isDone\\\": \\\"YES\\\", \\\"stage\\\": \\\"Preparations\\\", \\\"status\\\": \\\"Done \\\"}\"";
```

Another alternative is to create a DTO/Model class and then pass it like the way you are doing in your code.

Comment: Sending the json as string worked for me, Thank u , but i am thinking even when i convert the JObject to string it is null, have u got any idea why ?