# Is there a way to pass on a string from angular 7 to a .Net Core 2.0 API?

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, angular7

I am Trying to pass on a string from my angular 7 service to the .net API... but it always gives bad Content. Can anyone suggest me any solution?

ANGULAR:

```
searchAgentCode(agent_code:string): Observable<prsProducer[]>{
        debugger;
        let url: string=this._global.serviceUrl+'Producers/checkAgentCode';
        return this._httpClient.post<prsProducer[]>(url,agent_code);
      }
```

API:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Produces(typeof(List<ProducerDC>))]
        [Route("checkAgentCode")]
        public IActionResult checkAgentCode([FromBody]String obj_ProducerDC)
        {
            sys_ACTIVITY_LOG_Insert(Request);
            try
            {

                ProducerBL obj_ProducerBL = new ProducerBL();
                List<ProducerDC> producer = new List<ProducerDC>();
                //List<sys_USERDC> list = new List<sys_USERDC>();
                //list.Add(sys_USER);
                int UpdatedCount = 0;
                string agent_code = obj_ProducerDC.AGENT_CODE;
                producer = obj_ProducerBL.checkAgentCode(agent_code);
                return Ok(producer);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogException(ex);
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use Class object to store the parameter. and then send it to the API.

```
searchAgentCode(agent_code:string): Observable<prsProducer[]>{
        debugger;
Myclass myobj=new Myclass();
myobj.agent_code=agent_code;
        let url: string=this._global.serviceUrl+'Producers/checkAgentCode';
        return this._httpClient.post<prsProducer[]>(url,myobj);
      }
```

\

for the API, make the same class with the same properties, and receive the parameter in the class object as :

```
    [HttpPost]
            [Produces(typeof(List<ProducerDC>))]
            [Route("checkAgentCode")]
            public IActionResult checkAgentCode([FromBody]MyClassforAPI obj_ProducerDC)
            {
                sys_ACTIVITY_LOG_Insert(Request);
                try
                {
string agent_code= obj_ProducerDC.agent_code;
    //YOUR CODE
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    LogException(ex);
                    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually a preferable practice is to create a view model as for example [Hur Abbas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56831336/4792784) showed.

If passing a single string is a strict requirement for you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37842548/4792784) answer.

Depending on the REST approach followed on the project it might be also a solution to pass it as a route parameter

```
[Route("checkAgentCode/{obj_ProducerDC}")]
public IActionResult checkAgentCode(string obj_ProducerDC)
{
    // Logic here...
```