# How to upload an image with metadata like Description and title

Tags: image, post, xamarin, .net-core, image-uploading

I'm currently writing an WebApi endpoint that is to accept image uploads with associated Descriptions and titles.  I want to be able to send this information up in one post rather than sending the image and then the meta data in a subsequent call.

The client sending this is a mobile application written in Xamarin.

Searching the internet I struggled to fine any direction to doing this kind of thing although I'm sure it's possible.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: do you want to upload the image with embedded metadata?  Or do you need to extract the metadata and pass it as explicit arguments to the service?  It might help if you posted the signature of the service you're using

Comment: I haven't got the service signature yet as that's what I'm not sure how to do.  It doesn't have to be metadata but I just want a way to be able to pass up other data when I post the image at the same kind.  could be as query parameters or anything I guess.  Metadata might be a red herring I guess it's just data associated with the image

Comment: just create an endpoint that accepts a byte[] for the image data, then additional parameters for whatever additional parms you want to send

Comment: Really, it's that simple?  I assume then that that data is posted in the body of the request.  Would it have to be serilized to a string i.e. json or using some other format?

Comment: I'm not a WebAPI expert, you should be able to do something like that.  It would have to be a POST due to the size of the image. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184360/post-byte-array-to-web-api-server-using-httpclient

Answer (score 2):

USE CLOUDINARY

upload image to cloud  with easy api like

```
https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_150,h_150,c_thumb,g_face,r_20,e_sepia/l_cloudinary_icon,,x_5,y_5,w_50,o_60,e_brightness:200/a_10/front_face.png
```

[The DotNet SDK is here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/dotnet_integration)

[and a tutorial to add metadata along](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202521142-Can-I-add-metadata-to-images-)