# How to send ProtoBuf as bytes in HtttpClient?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, httpclient, protocol-buffers

Please find the below code which I used to send the bytes in HTTPCLIENT.

```
   public void SendProtoBufBytes(byte[] payload)
    {         

            #region WebAPI Call              

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                string baseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment"];
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));//For BINARY files - ("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");

                var byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(payload);

                HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("api/processwebjobs/processjobrequest", byteArrayContent).Result;

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string processServerResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                }

           }

            #endregion
        }
```

Here, **payload** is a ***ProtoBuf file which is converted into Bytes***.

***WebApi Method:***

```
[RoutePrefix("api/processwebjobs")]
public class ProcessWebJobsApiController : BaseApiController
{
    #region Public Api Methods

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("processjobrequest")]
    public IHttpActionResult ProcessJobRequest([FromBody] byte[] payload)
    {
    }
 }
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: You’ll want to POST it most likely, not try to put it into the query string. Especially if it may be a bit larger amount. Or you’ll need to encode it first if you really need to use GET.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Thanks for your quick response. Let me change to httppost and try.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I have tried with the HTTPPOST, But Still no luck. I have updated the Question to post method.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184360/post-byte-array-to-web-api-server-using-httpclient help?

Comment: @mjwills that link is helped! thank you, guys!