# Posting file with HttpClient to a Web Api

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing an ASP.NET Web Api 2 with C# and .NET Framework 4.7.

I'm trying to upload a file to the web api using a [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7) instance.

I have added this to Web.Config:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7" maxRequestLength="1048576" />

[ ... ]

<location path="ProductionOrderApi">
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="120" maxRequestLength="81920" />
  </system.web>
</location>

[ ... ]

<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

This is the web api method:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/ProductionOrder/{productionOrderName}/Processed")]
public HttpResponseMessage UploadProductionOrderProcessed(
    string productionOrderName,
    byte[] jsonData)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;

    try
    {
        Data.ProductionOrder po = repository
            .SearchFor(p => string.Equals(p.Name, productionOrderName) &&
                        p.Phase == (byte)Phase.Processed)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (po == null)
            response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        else
        {
            string json = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(jsonData);

            StoredProcedureErrors error = 
                StoredProcedures.LoadProcessedBatch(connectionString, json);

            if (error == StoredProcedureErrors.NoError)
                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
            else
            {
                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);

                exceptionLogger.LogMessage(
                    this.GetType().Name,
                    System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name,
                    "Database error: " + error);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        exceptionLogger.LogCompleteException(
            this.GetType().Name,
            System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name,
            ex);

        response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    }

    return response;
}
```

This is client to make the call:

```
public bool UploadProcessedBatch(string productionOrderName, byte[] jsonData)
{
    string completeUri = string.Format(UploadProcessedBatchUri, productionOrderName);

    return Post<byte[]>(completeUri, jsonData);
}

protected bool Post<T>(string completeUri, T dataToPost)
{
    if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(dataToPost, default(T)))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("dataToPost");

    bool result = false;

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_webApiHost);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataToPost), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = client.PostAsync(completeUri, content);
        HttpResponseMessage message = response.Result;

        result = (message.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created);

        LatestStatusCode = message.StatusCode;
        ReasonPhrase = message.ReasonPhrase;
    }

    return result;
}
```

If I make a call with PostMan without posting any `jsonData` it receives the call, but when I make a call with any `jsonData` it doesn't call it (I have a breakpoint at first line in Web Api method): I get an exception saying "Cancelled task" with anything else useful.

The file I'm trying to upload it is big (more than 7 MB).

Any idea about what is it happening?

I think the problem is how I sending the data. All the examples that I have found are about sending the data with a Html form but I haven't found anything about how to send it with a HttpClient.

Comment: "it doesn't call it" - but what is the response? There should be some error response (404 or something else).

Comment: @Evk I get an exception saying "Cancelled task" with anything else useful.

Comment: It's not very efficient to send files like this. Better use multipart content or pass some parameters in url (like `productionOrderName`) and pass file in response body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

So since Web Api 2.1 it is possible to use BSON, a "JSON-like" Format, which is able to send binary formatted data. In the [linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/bson-support-in-web-api-21) Article you'll even find an example using HttpClient.

Before the Introduction of BSON a common way around the limitation of JSON has been to encode the binary as base64.

**Orig:**

The short of it is you can't simply send a byte[] as a Json Property.

Possible work-arounds are:

1. Base64 parsing at Client/Server
2. Another possibility that i haven't been aware of until now is BSON. Look at the official [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/bson-support-in-web-api-21) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184360/post-byte-array-to-web-api-server-using-httpclient) Thread for more info.

Maybe someone else has something to add to that list.

Cheers,

Comment: Yes, I think the problem is how I sending the data. All the examples that I have found are about sending the data with a Html form but I haven't found anything about how to send it with a HttpClient. Thanks.

Comment: Then looking into BSON might be interesting for you. As pointed out I wasn't aware about that and only now looking it up. 
On the other hand base64 is a widely used encoding which you can use moreoften than not 'out-of-the-box'. It's easy to use but has a lot of overhead.