# getting a byte array to web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I don't see anywhere a simple example regarding how to get a file from an API user via web api.
here's my function signature ( modified for stackoverflow ) :

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Tasks/CreateTaskWithFileOption")]
    public TaskDetailsRequestModel CreateTaskWithFileOption(string token, int templateId, byte[] fileForSignature = null)
```

That i don't get values when trying to send a parameter to my service, what the right way to implement it ?  ( put aside authorization , the only thing i need is to understand how to pass that byte array )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184360/post-byte-array-to-web-api-server-using-httpclient

Comment: i don't see how can i send the data both and desalinize it ( both string , int & byte array ).

Comment: You can have two ways: 
var httpRequest = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;
                HttpFileCollection uploadFiles = httpRequest.Files;

var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
                await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
                foreach (var file in provider.Contents)
                {
                    var filename = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('\"');
                    Stream ste = await file.ReadAsStreamAsync();

}