# How to send post request with String and byte array parameters

Tags: java, http, post, android-volley

I need to send a byte array in a post request. I'm trying using volley, but I only know how to send post with only String parameters. Specifically I need to fill the following fields in the request:

```
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Id", ""));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Empresa", "1"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Matricula", "1"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Foto", bytearray[] here));  << this is the field that need byte array
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Data", "11/22/2020 16:30:00"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("GPS", "0"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idDispositivo", "0"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("arquivo", ""));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("face", "0"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ip", "0.0"));
```

I know that the method above doesn't work. It's just an example of how I have to fill the post request.

I saw this answer in C#: [Post byte array to Web API server using HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184360/post-byte-array-to-web-api-server-using-httpclient). I need something like that in Java.

Encoding the byte array in Base64 String doesn't solve my problem.

I accept any method that can solve my problem, I don't need specifically do the post request with volley.

PS.: Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. I was wrong about encoding the byte array in Base64 String. I thought that doesn't work because I was doing that with volley and did not work.

But I found a post method with JSON and it actually works. Here's the post method:

```
public void novoPost(String empresa, String matricula, byte[] foto, String data, String face) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("http://myurl.com");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        con.setDoOutput(true);

        String jsonInputString = "{\"Id\":" + "\"" + "" +  "\"" +  "," +
                "\"Empresa\":" + "\"" + empresa +  "\"" + "," +
                "\"Matricula\":" + "\"" + matricula +  "\"" + "," +
                "\"Foto\":" + "\"" + getStringImage(foto) +  "\"" + "," +
                "\"Data\":" + "\"" + data +  "\"" + "," +
                "\"GPS\":" + "\"" + getGPS() +  "\"" + "," +
                "\"idDispositivo\":" + "\"" + getIMEI() +  "\"" + "," +
                "\"arquivo\":" + "\"" + "" +  "\"" + "," +
                "\"face\":" + "\"" + face +  "\"" + "," +
                "\"ip\":" + "\"" + getIPAddress(true) +  "\"" + "," +
                "}";

        try (OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream()) {
            byte[] input = jsonInputString.getBytes("utf-8");
            os.write(input, 0, input.length);
        }

        int code = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println(code);

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "utf-8"))) {
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            String responseLine = null;
            while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(responseLine.trim());
            }
            System.out.println(response.toString());
        }
    }
```

and this is the method that encode the byte array into String:

```
public String getStringImage(byte[] bm) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream ba = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        String encode = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(bm, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encode;
    }
```