# How cURL POST image file works?

Tags: c#, facebook, curl, facebook-messenger

I am trying to use the new Facebook Messenger Platform API to send image message using image file from application directory.

Facebook gives the example using `cURL` like below:

```
curl  \
  -F recipient='{"id":"USER_ID"}' \
  -F message='{"attachment":{"type":"image", "payload":{}}}' \
  -F filedata=@/tmp/testpng.png \
  "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

But I am trying to use the API with `C#`. For your information, I have successfully use the API if I use the file from an internet url.

I have tried to fill in the `filedata` property by using `base64` string of the image file, but unsuccessful.

Kindly explain how does `cURL` works with the given file path especially image and create a POST request to the web server? And if possible, what options do I have to do it with `C#`?

Comment: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html can help you for everything related to cURL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -F option is for form. This is equivalent to issuing a POST request with the Content-Type header of multipart/formdata and the request body containing all the key-value pairs listed with a proper boundary set. cURL will read the binary data and put the bytes in the correct boundary in the request. There are many examples online for C# to submit a multipart/formdata request. Look into HttpClient or WebClient file uploads and you'll find what you need.

I'll be away from a computer for a few days and submitting sample code from a mobile device isn't the easiest thing to do. If you need some sample code, let me know.

Comment: additional information to create multipart/formdata request is on answer link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19664927/2601922