# Run a curl request in c#

Tags: c#, webrequest

I want to run a curl request given as

```
curl --data-binary @"/path/to/my.pdf" -H "Content-Type: application/pdf" -L "http://pdfx.cs.man.ac.uk"
```

This request simply sends a PDF file to http://pdfx.cs.man.ac.uk and in response this site return a XML file.
How it can be done in C#?

Comment: What did you try to run it, you can just run that - what specifically did you want to achieve?

Comment: You've got to create a process and execute the command from within the process. Check out http://askubuntu.com/questions/506985/c-opening-the-terminal-process-and-pass-commands

Comment: `Process.Start` maybe?

Comment: Have you looked at the `WebRequest`, `WebClient`, or `HttpClient` classes in .NET?

Comment: I would echo the above comment. .NET has its own built-in classes for making HTTP requests. Using an external tool like curl is unnecessary and overcomplicates things.

Comment: @BugFinder I'll manipulate the returned XML file further for my own project.

Comment: @ShahbazAhmadSahi that didnt answer what I said one tiny tiny bit

Comment: @IanMercer how can I send the web request, that contains the PDF file with it. Any reference?

Comment: @ShahbazAhmadSahi "how can I send the web request that contains the PDF file...?" https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=C%23+send+web+request+pdf+file here are lots of references.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to reproduce form POST action in C#. One way is to use `HttpClient` from `this package` (.NET 4.0) or directly if working in .NET 4.5+.

A fully working example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19664927/2780791). Basically you have to:

- you initialize the http client
- initialize form data
- post the data
- wait for the response

You can also set the content type of posted content (in your case `application/pdf)`, by following the provided answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679214/how-do-you-set-the-content-type-header-for-an-httpclient-request).