# Why do I get a 404 when trying to post content from a zip file vs a normal text file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, httpclient, mime-types, dotnet-httpclient

I have an MVC cross Web API app that has an `ApiFileController`, headed:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/File")]
public class ApiFileController : ApiBaseController
```

It has the following action method

```
[HttpPost("PostDir")]
[DisableRequestSizeLimit]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostDir(string serverPath)
{
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(serverPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        await Request.Body.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

that is supposed to received a zipfile containing a directory, and unzip it into the `serverPath` parameter. Yet when I try and post a file as follows:

```
sourcePath = Path.Combine("Temp", Guid.NewGuid() + ".zip");
System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(localPath, sourcePath, CompressionLevel.Fastest, true);
...
using (var fileStream = File.Open(sourcePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
    using (var content = new StreamContent(reader.BaseStream))
    {
        var uri = $"api/File/PostDir?serverPath={WebUtility.UrlEncode(serverPath)}";
        var resp = await _client.PostAsync(uri, content);
        resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
}
```

I get a 404 - Not found. If I post a plain text file, as follows,

```
    using (var fileStream = File.Open(localPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
        using (var content = new StreamContent(reader.BaseStream))
        {
            var uri = $"api/File/PostDir?serverPath={WebUtility.UrlEncode(serverPath)}";
            var resp = await _client.PostAsync(uri, content);
            resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
    }
```

where `localPath` points to a plain text file, the `PostDir` action is correctly invoked and properly saves the text file.

I am using `HttpClient`, in a wrapper class, to make the requests, and it is initialized in the wrapper's ctor as follows:

```
public ApiClient()
{
    var baseAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiUrl"];
    _client = new HttpClient();
    _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = false;
    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
}
```

I suspect that when posting the binary zip files, I am missing a content type header or such. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any particular reason you are posting the file in the body?

Comment: @AmanB I am new to `HttpClient`, and all examples I have successfully followed, and all my working code based on them, post the file in the body. Simple as that.

Comment: In that case, try posting request body as `MultipartFormDataContent` and then you can access the files using `Request.Files` collection on the receiving end. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131425/send-a-file-via-http-post-with-c-sharp

Comment: Check/set the content type of the stream being sent to the server. By default it will accept text.

Comment: @Nkosi I don't know exactly what header and what value to set for the content type with this zip file.

Comment: The action method code you've shown is called "PostDir" The URL you appear to be calling is called "PostFile" Have you shown us the wrong action method? Anyway as the others have pointed out, you can't send binary data (i.e. almost any type of file which isn't text) without setting the correct content type in your request.

Comment: Try setting the content type for the zip file before posting`content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/zip");`

Comment: @ADyson That was a typo on my part. I had copied code to notepad before changing it, then posted the code from notepad. Anyway, I have now grokked that I have to set a correct content type header, and even before editing, the last part of my question was just how to do so.

Comment: @Nkosi Nope, with that header, or `application/octet-stream`, I still get a 404.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't take my code as gospel on how to upload a zip file, but it turns out the error was that I had only used the `[DisableRequestSizeLimit]` attribute on the action method, and that only disables Kestrel's request size limit. IIS still has a 30MB limit which I disabled by adding a `web.config` with the following:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <!-- 1 GB -->
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```