# How to receive multipart form data in Azure Function?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

This answer explains how one can **send** multipart form data via HTTP POST in C#:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19664927/10779

Code quoted from answer:

```
private async Task<System.IO.Stream> Upload(string actionUrl, string paramString, Stream paramFileStream, byte [] paramFileBytes)
{
    HttpContent stringContent = new StringContent(paramString);
    HttpContent fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(paramFileStream);
    HttpContent bytesContent = new ByteArrayContent(paramFileBytes);
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        formData.Add(stringContent, "param1", "param1");
        formData.Add(fileStreamContent, "file1", "file1");
        formData.Add(bytesContent, "file2", "file2");
        var response = await client.PostAsync(actionUrl, formData);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    }
}
```

How would you properly receive such a POST request in an Azure function?

It seems the `HttpRequest` Form property (`req.Form["file1"]`) always gives you a string instead of access to a stream. How do you correctly get the original byte[] data for the "file1" or "file2" key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default template creates an Azure function with a `HttpRequest` parameter. Turns out you can change this to a `HttpRequestMessage` parameter and then use `req.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync()` to read individual multiform parts.

Comment: Could you please help me with python version as well?

Comment: @Abhijeet sorry, I can't help but you could post a new question and ask all the python experts.

Comment: Yes, Sure. I will do that